How to create a function that accepts a DevicePath (\Device\Harddiskvolume3) or a Drive Letter (C) and then outputs specified information in Pwsh 7?
I found this post on Superuser,
And I've been using a modified version of the script in that post to effectively list all drives and various information:

function Get-AllDriveInfo {

    $signature =
@'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszVolumeName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeNamePaths, uint cchBuferLength,
        ref UInt32 lpcchReturnLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindFirstVolume([Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName,
    uint cchBufferLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool FindNextVolume(IntPtr hFindVolume, [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName, uint cchBufferLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

'@;
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Utils -Namespace PInvoke -Using PInvoke, System.Text;

    [UInt32] $lpcchReturnLength = 0;
    [UInt32] $Max = 65535
    $sbVolumeName = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max, $Max)
    $sbPathName = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max, $Max)
    $sbMountPoint = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max, $Max)
    [IntPtr] $volumeHandle = [PInvoke.Win32Utils]::FindFirstVolume($sbVolumeName, $Max)
    do {
        $volume = $sbVolumeName.toString()
        $unused = [PInvoke.Win32Utils]::GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW($volume, $sbMountPoint, $Max, [Ref] $lpcchReturnLength);
        $ReturnLength = [PInvoke.Win32Utils]::QueryDosDevice($volume.Substring(4, $volume.Length - 1 - 4), $sbPathName, [UInt32] $Max);
        if ($ReturnLength) {

            $DriveLetter = ($sbMountPoint.toString() -replace ':\\','')
            $VolumeData = Get-Volume -UniqueId $volume | Select-Object *
            $PartitionData = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter | Select-Object *

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DriveLetter = $DriveLetter
                DevicePath = $sbPathName.ToString()
                DiskNumber = $PartitionData.DiskNumber
                HealthStatus = $VolumeData.HealthStatus
                DriveType = $VolumeData.DriveType
                FileSystem = $VolumeData.FileSystemType
                AllocationUnitSize = $VolumeData.AllocationUnitSize
                FriendlyLabel = $VolumeData.FileSystemLabel
                Capacity = Format-Bytes -Bytes $VolumeData.Size
                RemainingSpace = Format-Bytes -Bytes $VolumeData.SizeRemaining
                VolumeName = $volume
                GptType = $PartitionData.GptType
                GUID = $PartitionData.Guid
                IsActive  = $PartitionData.IsActive
                IsBoot = $PartitionData.IsBoot
                IsDAX = $PartitionData.IsDAX
                IsHidden = $PartitionData.IsHidden
                IsOffline = $PartitionData.IsOffline
                IsReadOnly = $PartitionData.IsReadOnly
                IsShadowCopy = $PartitionData.IsShadowCopy
                IsSystem = $PartitionData.IsSystem
                MbrType = $PartitionData.MbrType
                Offset = $PartitionData.Offset
            }

        } else {
            Write-Output "No mountpoint found for: " + $volume
        }
    } while ([PInvoke.Win32Utils]::FindNextVolume([IntPtr] $volumeHandle, $sbVolumeName, $Max));
}

Get-AllDriveInfo

But what I really want now is to create a function that lists data only for a passed in drive (Either in drive letter format, or DevicePath format (\Device\HarddiskvolumeX).
The code is quite a bit over my head, so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. The idea is:
function Get-SpecificDriveInfo {

    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName="DriveLetter")]
        $DriveLetter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName="DevicePath")]
        $DevicePath
    )

    ... Code to isolate the drive and print information.

}

# Usage:
Get-SpecificDriveInfo -DevicePath '\Device\HarddiskVolume3'
Get-SpecificDriveInfo -DriveLetter 'C'

I know I'm asking for quite a bit of hand-holding but I just can't wrap my head around some of the more advanced PInvoke.Win32Utils functions and how they work.
Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Go to https://www.pinvoke.net/ which contains the definition for all window dlls.  I get an error when running the code because I do not have the cmdlet Format-Bytes

Try using GetVolumeInformation : https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetVolumeInformation

Actually, the changes will be quite small:
function Get-SpecificDriveInfo {

    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName="DriveLetter")]
        [String]$DriveLetter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName="DevicePath")]
        [String]$DevicePath
    )

    $signature =
@'
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool 
GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpszVolumeName,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] [Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeNamePaths, uint cchBuferLength,
    ref UInt32 lpcchReturnLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindFirstVolume([Out] StringBuilder lpszVolumeName,
uint cchBufferLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool FindNextVolume(IntPtr hFindVolume, [Out] 
StringBuilder lpszVolumeName, uint cchBufferLength);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint QueryDosDevice(string lpDeviceName, StringBuilder 
lpTargetPath, int ucchMax);

'@;
    Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Utils -Namespace PInvoke -Using PInvoke, System.Text;

    [UInt32] $lpcchReturnLength = 0;
    [UInt32] $Max = 65535
    $sbVolumeName = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max, $Max)
    $sbPathName = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max, $Max)
    $sbMountPoint = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder($Max, $Max)
    [IntPtr] $volumeHandle = [PInvoke.Win32Utils]::FindFirstVolume($sbVolumeName, $Max)
    do {
        $volume = $sbVolumeName.toString()
        $unused = [PInvoke.Win32Utils]::GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeNameW($volume, $sbMountPoint, $Max, [Ref] $lpcchReturnLength);
        $ReturnLength = [PInvoke.Win32Utils]::QueryDosDevice($volume.Substring(4, $volume.Length - 1 - 4), $sbPathName, [UInt32] $Max);
        if ($ReturnLength) {
            $Drive_Letter = ($sbMountPoint.toString() -replace ':\\','')
            $VolumeData = Get-Volume -UniqueId $volume | Select-Object *
            $PartitionData = Get-Partition -DriveLetter $DriveLetter | Select-Object *
            #my change
            if ((($Drive_Letter -eq $DriveLetter) -and ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DriveLetter'))) -or (($sbPathName.ToString() -eq $DevicePath)) -and ($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('DevicePath'))) {
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    DriveLetter = $Drive_Letter
                    DevicePath = $sbPathName.ToString()
                    DiskNumber = $PartitionData.DiskNumber
                    HealthStatus = $VolumeData.HealthStatus
                    DriveType = $VolumeData.DriveType
                    FileSystem = $VolumeData.FileSystemType
                    AllocationUnitSize = $VolumeData.AllocationUnitSize
                    FriendlyLabel = $VolumeData.FileSystemLabel
                    Capacity = Format-Bytes -Bytes $VolumeData.Size
                    RemainingSpace = Format-Bytes -Bytes $VolumeData.SizeRemaining
                    VolumeName = $volume
                    GptType = $PartitionData.GptType
                    GUID = $PartitionData.Guid
                    IsActive  = $PartitionData.IsActive
                    IsBoot = $PartitionData.IsBoot
                    IsDAX = $PartitionData.IsDAX
                    IsHidden = $PartitionData.IsHidden
                    IsOffline = $PartitionData.IsOffline
                    IsReadOnly = $PartitionData.IsReadOnly
                    IsShadowCopy = $PartitionData.IsShadowCopy
                    IsSystem = $PartitionData.IsSystem
                    MbrType = $PartitionData.MbrType
                    Offset = $PartitionData.Offset
                }
            }

        } else {
            Write-Output "No mountpoint found for: " + $volume
        }
    } while ([PInvoke.Win32Utils]::FindNextVolume([IntPtr] $volumeHandle, $sbVolumeName, $Max));
}

# Usage:
Get-SpecificDriveInfo -DevicePath '\Device\HarddiskVolume3'
Get-SpecificDriveInfo -DriveLetter 'C'

I added one comparison block that checks if a parameter is given and what it is equal to.

@fmotion1 you could mark the answer as a solution if it helped you
